# when trying to debugging an C# program by using VS code,says"prelaunchtask 'build'has been terminated, exit code is 1",how to solve it?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code

**F5 failed during debugging, showing: prelaunchtask "build" has been terminated, the exit code is 1.**

Ive tried multiple variations of this, but none of them seem to work. Any ideas?sincerely ask!

The C # extension error is displayed in the lower right corner of vscode, the error message is as follows

```
Starting OmniSharp server at 2020/4/30 下午3:01:54
    Target: e:\VisualStudioCode\C#

OmniSharp server started.
    Path: C:\Users\El Psy\.vscode\extensions\ms-dotnettools.csharp-1.21.17\.omnisharp\1.35.1-beta.32\OmniSharp.exe
    PID: 1952

[info]: OmniSharp.Stdio.Host
        Starting OmniSharp on Windows 6.2.9200.0 (x64)
[info]: OmniSharp.Services.DotNetCliService
        DotNetPath set to dotnet
[info]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.Discovery.MSBuildLocator
        Located 1 MSBuild instance(s)
            1: StandAlone 16.4 - "C:\Users\El Psy\.vscode\extensions\ms-dotnettools.csharp-1.21.17\.omnisharp\1.35.1-beta.32\.msbuild\Current\Bin"
[info]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.Discovery.MSBuildLocator
        MSBUILD_EXE_PATH environment variable set to 'C:\Users\El Psy\.vscode\extensions\ms-dotnettools.csharp-1.21.17\.omnisharp\1.35.1-beta.32\.msbuild\Current\Bin\MSBuild.exe'
[info]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.Discovery.MSBuildLocator
        Registered MSBuild instance: StandAlone 16.4 - "C:\Users\El Psy\.vscode\extensions\ms-dotnettools.csharp-1.21.17\.omnisharp\1.35.1-beta.32\.msbuild\Current\Bin"
            CscToolExe = csc.exe
            CscToolPath = C:\Users\El Psy\.vscode\extensions\ms-dotnettools.csharp-1.21.17\.omnisharp\1.35.1-beta.32\.msbuild\Current\Bin\Roslyn
            MSBuildExtensionsPath = C:\Users\El Psy\.vscode\extensions\ms-dotnettools.csharp-1.21.17\.omnisharp\1.35.1-beta.32\.msbuild
            MSBuildToolsPath = C:\Users\El Psy\.vscode\extensions\ms-dotnettools.csharp-1.21.17\.omnisharp\1.35.1-beta.32\.msbuild\Current\Bin
[info]: OmniSharp.Cake.CakeProjectSystem
        Detecting Cake files in 'e:\VisualStudioCode\C#'.
[info]: OmniSharp.Cake.CakeProjectSystem
        Could not find any Cake files
[info]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectSystem
        No solution files found in 'e:\VisualStudioCode\C#'
[info]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager
        Queue project update for 'e:\VisualStudioCode\C#\C#.csproj'
[info]: OmniSharp.Script.ScriptProjectSystem
        Detecting CSX files in 'e:\VisualStudioCode\C#'.
[info]: OmniSharp.Script.ScriptProjectSystem
        Could not find any CSX files
[info]: OmniSharp.WorkspaceInitializer
        Invoking Workspace Options Provider: OmniSharp.Roslyn.CSharp.Services.CSharpFormattingWorkspaceOptionsProvider, Order: 0
[info]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager
        Loading project: e:\VisualStudioCode\C#\C#.csproj
[info]: OmniSharp.WorkspaceInitializer
        Invoking Workspace Options Provider: OmniSharp.Roslyn.CSharp.Services.RenameWorkspaceOptionsProvider, Order: 100
[info]: OmniSharp.WorkspaceInitializer
        Invoking Workspace Options Provider: OmniSharp.Roslyn.CSharp.Services.ImplementTypeWorkspaceOptionsProvider, Order: 110
[info]: OmniSharp.WorkspaceInitializer
        Invoking Workspace Options Provider: OmniSharp.Roslyn.CSharp.Services.BlockStructureWorkspaceOptionsProvider, Order: 140
[info]: OmniSharp.WorkspaceInitializer
        Configuration finished.
[info]: OmniSharp.Stdio.Host
        Omnisharp server running using Stdio at location 'e:\VisualStudioCode\C#' on host 14876.
[fail]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectLoader
        The "ResolvePackageAssets" task failed unexpectedly.
NuGet.Packaging.Core.PackagingException: Unable to find fallback package folder 'C:\Microsoft\Xamarin\NuGet\'.
   在 NuGet.Packaging.FallbackPackagePathResolver..ctor(String userPackageFolder, IEnumerable`1 fallbackPackageFolders)
   在 Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks.NuGetPackageResolver.CreateResolver(IEnumerable`1 packageFolders)
   在 Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks.ResolvePackageAssets.CacheWriter..ctor(ResolvePackageAssets task)
   在 Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks.ResolvePackageAssets.CacheReader.CreateReaderFromDisk(ResolvePackageAssets task, Byte[] settingsHash)
   在 Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks.ResolvePackageAssets.CacheReader..ctor(ResolvePackageAssets task)
   在 Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks.ResolvePackageAssets.ReadItemGroups()
   在 Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks.ResolvePackageAssets.ExecuteCore()
   在 Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks.TaskBase.Execute()
   在 Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
   在 Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.<ExecuteInstantiatedTask>d__26.MoveNext()
[warn]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager
        Failed to load project file 'e:\VisualStudioCode\C#\C#.csproj'.
e:\VisualStudioCode\C#\C#.csproj
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\3.1.201\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.PackageDependencyResolution.targets(234,5): Error: The "ResolvePackageAssets" task failed unexpectedly.
NuGet.Packaging.Core.PackagingException: Unable to find fallback package folder 'C:\Microsoft\Xamarin\NuGet\'.
   在 NuGet.Packaging.FallbackPackagePathResolver..ctor(String userPackageFolder, IEnumerable`1 fallbackPackageFolders)
   在 Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks.NuGetPackageResolver.CreateResolver(IEnumerable`1 packageFolders)
   在 Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks.ResolvePackageAssets.CacheWriter..ctor(ResolvePackageAssets task)
   在 Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks.ResolvePackageAssets.CacheReader.CreateReaderFromDisk(ResolvePackageAssets task, Byte[] settingsHash)
   在 Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks.ResolvePackageAssets.CacheReader..ctor(ResolvePackageAssets task)
   在 Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks.ResolvePackageAssets.ReadItemGroups()
   在 Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks.ResolvePackageAssets.ExecuteCore()
   在 Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks.TaskBase.Execute()
   在 Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
   在 Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.<ExecuteInstantiatedTask>d__26.MoveNext()

[fail]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager
        Attempted to update project that is not loaded: e:\VisualStudioCode\C#\C#.csproj
```

tasks.json

```
     {//tasks.json
       // See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
       // for the documentation about the tasks.json format
       "version": "2.0.0",
       "tasks": [
           {
               "label": "build",
               "command": "dotnet",
               "type": "shell",
               "args": [
                   "build",
                   // Ask dotnet build to generate full paths for file names.
                   "/property:GenerateFullPaths=true",
                   // Do not generate summary otherwise it leads to duplicate errors in Problems panel
                   "/consoleloggerparameters:NoSummary"
               ],
               "group": "build",
               "presentation": {
                   "reveal": "silent"
               },
               "problemMatcher": "$msCompile"
           }
       ]
   }
```

launch.json;

```
    {
        // launch.json;

        "version": "0.2.0",
        "configurations": [

            {
                "name": ".NET Core Launch (console)",
                "type": "coreclr",
                "request": "launch",
                "WARNING01": "*********************************************************************************",
                "WARNING02": "The C# extension was unable to automatically decode projects in the current",
                "WARNING03": "workspace to create a runnable launch.json file. A template launch.json file has",
                "WARNING04": "been created as a placeholder.",
                "WARNING05": "",
                "WARNING06": "If OmniSharp is currently unable to load your project, you can attempt to resolve",
                "WARNING07": "this by restoring any missing project dependencies (example: run 'dotnet restore')",
                "WARNING08": "and by fixing any reported errors from building the projects in your workspace.",
                "WARNING09": "If this allows OmniSharp to now load your project then --",
                "WARNING10": "  * Delete this file",
                "WARNING11": "  * Open the Visual Studio Code command palette (View->Command Palette)",
                "WARNING12": "  * run the command: '.NET: Generate Assets for Build and Debug'.",
                "WARNING13": "",
                "WARNING14": "If your project requires a more complex launch configuration, you may wish to delete",
                "WARNING15": "this configuration and pick a different template using the 'Add Configuration...'",
                "WARNING16": "button at the bottom of this file.",
                "WARNING17": "*********************************************************************************",
                "preLaunchTask": "build",
                "program": "${workspaceFolder}/bin/Debug/<insert-target-framework-here>/<insert-project-name-here>.dll",
                "args": [],
                "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
                "console": "internalConsole",
                "stopAtEntry": false
            },
            {
                "name": ".NET Core Attach",
                "type": "coreclr",
                "request": "attach",
                "processId": "${command:pickProcess}"
            }
        ]
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem can occur due to code in **tasks.json**. The possibility is that with the latest vscode, all the warnings in the console were treated as errors.
Try removing this line of configuration "problemMatcher": "$msCompile" (in tasks.json). Or just use the below code for your tasks.json

```
 "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "build",
            "command": "dotnet",
            "type": "process",
            "args": [
                "build",
                "${workspaceFolder}/c#.csproj",
                "/property:GenerateFullPaths=true",
                "/consoleloggerparameters:NoSummary"
            ],
            "problemMatcher": "$msCompile"
        }
```